# Tumblr addthis to theme exclude from 'submit' & 'ask' pages

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I added a              `<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" data-url="{Permalink}" data-title="{Title}"></div>` to my theme. The code works fine, except I would like to exclude it from the "Submit a Post" and "Ask Me Anything" pages. Can't seem to find a way to do that. Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in `{block:Date}` blocks likes so:

```
{block:Date}<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" data-url="{Permalink}" data-title="{Title}"></div>{/block:Date}
```

It works because those types of pages do not have a "date" associated with them. This will also hide it on any additional tumblr pages you create, but not post pages.

Additionally, to achieve the inverse of this, there is no official way but a workaround I have used in the past was to have something along the lines of

```
{block:PermalinkPage}<div class="{block:Date}x-{/block:Date}non-post">
...
</div>{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

And then having some CSS along the lines of

```
.x-non-post {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is there an inverse to that so that code only shows on the submit / ask pages and not the permalink pages?